# C function and struct on the fly

Tags: c, function, struct, on-the-fly

I would to know if t's possible in to initialise struct on the fly for function call like in c++ :

```
struct point {
  int x;
  int y;
};

some_function(new point(x,y));
```

Thx :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. You can use [compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html), introduced in C99.

```
some_function((struct pint) {5, 10});
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think, you should point out, that the structure's storage duration ends with the end of the enclosing block. And afaik there is no way of doing something similar with dynamic memory.

Comment: @mafso As the `struct` is passed by value anyway (this question is about C, not C++), the argument about its lifetime is mute.

Comment: Note that the parentheses around the function argument are superfluous. `some_function((struct point){5, 10});` works just as well.

Comment: @cmaster: Yes, you're totally right. But in the question, a pointer is passed. So this is not really equivalent. But yes, the lifetime is not the problem.

Comment: @cmaster; Yes. I often do mistake in parenthesizing :)

Comment: For `new`-like approach, just make a function that will `malloc` and fill fields. Also, in C99 structures could be assigned to each other, so `*ptr_to_struct = (type){1, 2, 3}` is quite valid.

Comment: @mafso Ah, yes, I see what you mean. Then again, `new` is not even a keyword in C, and its usage indicates to me that the OP seems to have a strong Java background (there is no such thing as an object on the stack in Java). So I guessed that what he really meant was to pass a throwaway object, which should be passed on the stack in C (as const reference in C++).

Comment: It is worth noting that compound literals are lvalues, which means that one can also do `some_function(&(struct pint) {5, 10})`. This is a bit closer to the original request in a sense that it produces a pointer argument (but it does not produce dynamic lifetime, of course).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in C and call your function like this guy said, but you'll need to add the flag -std=c99 to your gcc invocation line, else it might failed if you're using some -W* flags.